# Can ping from PC to cisco router's ipv6 address (from LAN side) but can't ping from one pc to other's ipv6 address

Tags: ipv6, ping

PCs are connected to Cisco switch and up link goes to `Cisco 1841` router 
on router LAN side interface f0/0 ip add: `2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::64/120`.
IPv6 is not enabled.

I am not able to give prefix length in Windows XP. but I can give prefix in Windows 7 machine.

**output of ipconfig from pc1:**

```
Ethernet Adapter Local Area Connection: 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . 
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0 
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::a 
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::d465:d174:df76:f501%13 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
                                    2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::64
```

My problem is I can ping from PC to router's `f0/0:2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::64`
and from router to PC also. But I can't ping from pc1(`2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::a`) to pc2(`2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::b`), whereas I can ping IPv4 address of pc2.
and firewall is off on every pc.

Comment: Where is PC2 in all this in relation to PC1 and the router?

Comment: Why do you have a prefix length of `/120`? This is nonstandard and will cause many things to break. In particular, XP and 2003 cannot be made to handle it at all. There is no way. Use the standard `/64` prefix and save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: Pc2 has similar IP address in same lan segment..

Comment: Pc2 is connected to same switch means in same lan network.. Pc2: 192.168.1.11, 2001:xx:xx:xx:1000::b

Comment: Actually we thought that by using 120 prefix length we can have 2 digits to configure ipv6 address just like ipv4 address's 4th octet(11 is b)..Any other problem with the configuration.friends??

Comment: and sorry by mistake i have written that ipv6 is not enabled.

Comment: i haven't given command ipv6 unicast-routing on 1841 router.